# How to convert list of string into list of integer in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, binary, integer

If I have a list of binary

```
a=['0b11001000', '0b01001100', '0b00111100', '0b00011111', 
   '0b11110000', '0b01011010', '0b10010110', '0b00011110']
```

I'd like to convert all the string elements into integers and put it back nicely to list of binary this time:

```
a=[0b11001000, 0b01001100, 0b00111100, 0b00011111, 
   0b11110000, 0b01011010, 0b10010110, 0b00011110]
```

What shall I do?

Answer (score 6):

Use `int` with base 2:

```
>>> a=['0b11001000', '0b01001100', '0b00111100', '0b00011111', 
...        '0b11110000', '0b01011010', '0b10010110', '0b00011110']
>>> [int(x, 2) for x in a]
[200, 76, 60, 31, 240, 90, 150, 30]
```

Answer (score 5):

Give this a try:

```
a = [int(x, 2) for x in a]
```

Answer (score 4):

Though in your second list you express the integers as binary, they are still of type `int`.  You can convert the strings, however:

```
a = [int(x, 2) for x in a]
```